# Get/Set cookie while using dart web app http

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I am working on an AngularDart web app.
I need to retrieve a cookie from a json server that works with cookie authentication.
So on connection, I have to post credentials in body, then the server give me back a response containing the cookie.

```
import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
Response response = await _http.post(_loginUrl, body: json.encode(datas));
```

The response is ok, I get 200 statuscode and the json response from the server, but impossible to find the cookie while in Postman I do get it.
So how to retrieve cookies from response?

EDIT: Informations returned from the server to postman :

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=03e95c12-6098-4f07-b9a9-054377b0311d; path=/; domain=.www.xxxxx.fr; HttpOnly; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```

EDIT: This is the raw headers from the server to the Dart app :

```
t=1462088 [st=142]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                          --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                              Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
                              Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                              Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=f229a77e-5eb6-4c6c-9c57-9280947cb434; path=/; HttpOnly
                              X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
                              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                              Date: Fri, 30 Nov 2018 09:52:50 GMT
                              Content-Length: 22443
```

So the server sends back the cookie, but the browser does not seem to save it ...

Ok so finally, a problem was found on the API server, the developer did not check correctly the cookie. Generally, only one cookie is sent to this server, so in its code, it took the first... But from a browser, severals cookie can be sent at the same time. So he made some change to check the good one...

Answer (score 0):

Postman should show that this is an `HttpOnly` cookie that can't be read from JavaScript (and the same applies for Dart of course)

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies

The cookie will be sent back to the server automatically therefore there is no need to read it from JavaScript. Allowing access from JavaScript only undermines security.

Comment: That's the problem, the cookie is not sent back to the server automatically and I don't know why. I tried in http & https.

Comment: Perhaps the server you are accessing is not the same as the one that issued the cookie. A different port is already considered a different server for the browser.

Comment: It is exactly the same

Comment: I don't know what else could cause this but sending it "manually" is not the solution, it rather invalidates the whole attempt to secure the app with authentication.

Comment: I agree, for instance, I made a server proxy to get around the cookie

Comment: I think it's a server issue. Probably some property the server sets for the cookie. Can you post the information you get from Postman about the cookie?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184508/discussion-between-ebelair-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious with your cookie and I doubt I can't provide more insight.

Comment: Finally, I found the answer..... There was a bug on the server ... The developer has made some corrections and now it's working.... make me crazy lol

Comment: We've all been there :D Would be interesting what these corrections were to add it as answer or comment for future "victims".